# BASH File Spaces

Tags: linux, bash, file, scripting, path

Hi but it appears that if my strings have spaces in it, it won't work properly. My entire script is here:

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo $#; echo $@
MoveToTarget() {
    #This takes to 2 arguments: source and target
        echo ""$1"  "$2""
    cp -rf "$1"/* "$2"
    rm -r "$1"
}

WaitForProcessToEnd() {
    #This takes 1 argument. The PID to wait for
    #Unlike the AutoIt version, this sleeps 1 second
    while [ $(kill -0 "$1") ]; do
            sleep 1
    done
}

RunApplication() {
    #This takes 1 application, the path to the thing to execute
    open "$1"
}

#our main code block
pid="$1"
SourcePath="$2"
DestPath="$3"
ToExecute="$4"
WaitForProcessToEnd $pid
MoveToTarget "$SourcePath" "$DestPath"
RunApplication "$ToExecute"
exit
```

Note that I have tried the variables like $DestPath with and without quotes around them, with no luck. This code gets run with a Python script, and when the arguments are passed, quotes are around them.  I appreciate any help!

Edit: (Python script)

```
bootstrapper_command = r'"%s" "%s" "%s" "%s" "%s"' % (bootstrapper_path, os.getpid(), extracted_path, self.app_path, self.postexecute)
shell = True
subprocess.Popen(bootstrapper_command, shell=shell)
```

Comment: Could you show the Python script?

Comment: a general debug tip, run it using `#!/bin/bash -x` then every variable with it's value is echoed to stdout as the script executes.

Comment: Could you `echo $#; echo $@` at the top of the script?  That might shed a little light.

Comment: "when the arguments are passed, quotes are around them" is wrong.

Comment: @Sorpigal I looked up on how to do it, I don't see the green arrow below my questions. Is it because I haven't registered?

Comment: `echo ""$1" "$2""` isn't going to do what you probably want under all circumstances.  I suggest "'$1' '$2'"

Comment: The echoing was just for debugging, it doesn't have a real purpose. I should have removed it before putting it on here. Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, I've just added some more output. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: I apologize everyone! I have a fairly complex setup where the bash script is downloaded (with a link to a JSON file). I made a mistake in this JSON file causing the wrong version to be downloaded. It is now working - gosh I feel stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Bash quotes are syntactic, not literal. [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments), as usual, has the most excellent explanation you could wish for.

Comment: Very useful info there.  I'd +1 Greg too if I could

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the *, it isn't needed for recursive copy.

```
cp -rf "$1"/* "$2"
```

to:

```
cp -rf "$1/" "$2"
```

I think globbing was ruining your quoting that was protecting you from spaces in filenames.